# User still logged in after doing logout when using my own Authentication class (Spring MVC)

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

Instead of putting the user info in a Session, I extended the Spring classes `User` creating a field user.

```
public class MyUser extends User {
   ...
}
```

Then I extended the Spring class `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` to "put" inside it my User class

```
 public class MyUsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken {                   
         private static final long serialVersionUID = -1353194962481509967L;        
         public MyUsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(Object details, MyUser myUser, Object credentials, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {            
                super(myUser, credentials, authorities);    
                super.setDetails(details);      
         }    
}
```

I have also extended the class `SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler`, to do some stuff after the user logs in successfully

```
    public class CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler{

public void onAuthenticationSuccess(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest request, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws IOException, javax.servlet.ServletException {

      MyUsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken myUsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken = //here I do some stuff to create my myUsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken ;

        super.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, myUsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);

        // I put myUsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken inside the Context
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(myUsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken );

            }

}
```

of course, I've extended also the Spring class `SimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler`

```
public class CustomLogoutSuccessHandler extends SimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler {

public void onLogoutSuccess(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest request, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws IOException, javax.servlet.ServletException{
        super.setDefaultTargetUrl("/pbl/login");
        super.onLogoutSuccess(request, response, authentication);

// in this method I tryed many types of cose, but I alwasy get the SessionAuthenticationException error.
//I don't show you all my old codes, since it didn't work and I don't want you to read other boring code.
}

}
```

Everything works except for ont thing. If I log out from a browser and then I try to log in from **another browser** I get the `SessionAuthenticationException` error, that tells me that the user is **still logged in**.
If I log out from a broswer and then I try to log in **from the same browser** I don't get any error.

IMPORTANT: before extending the classes `User`, `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` etc, my `SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler` worked perfectly and I didn't get any `SessionAuthenticationException` errors.

Can sombody help me?

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT**

if I add

```
HttpSession session = (HttpSession)request.getSession();
session.invalidate();
```

inside the method `onLogoutSuccess` everything seems to work correctly, but i can't understand why.

**SOLUTION.**

I made a big mastake inside my configuration file :

```
<security:logout                    
    ...                                  
    invalidate-session="false" // false instead of true
    ... />
```

Thank everybody for the help.

Comment: You are also doing way to much... You don't need a custom `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` you can simply use the default one. You can simply use the default one, spring will take care of setting everything else. Also your shouldn't mess around with setting in in a success handler. I would say apart from the logout issues you also have other issues because you are overriding too much.

Comment: Thank you for your advices. Actually I have to extend all the classes I extended, since I have to put some code inside them. I didn't show you that code to not bother you reading much code :)

Comment: You still shouldn't need all that, the specifics should be located to a custom userdetailsservice. Generally you shouldn't be modifying the context etc. outside a userdetailsservice/authenticatin provider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my knowledge, I think your `logout` functionality isn't working properly. Let's have a look at 2 scenarios you mentioned:

**Everything works except for ont thing. If I log out from a browser and then I try to log in from another browser I get the SessionAuthenticationException error, that tells me that the user is still logged in.**

This is happening because, your logout isn't working and your previous session isn't destroyed yet and spring-security doesn't allow a user to have 2 active session simultaneously you allow concurrent login in your application by adding additional support.

So, When you try to login from different browser spring-security throws exception that user is already logged in.

**If I log out from a browser and then I try to log in from the same browser I don't get any error.**

In 2nd case, as you are not logged out from the system. Therefore, when you log in again from the same browser, spring-security uses your previous session and allows you to enter application.

By invalidating session in your success handler, you are forcefully destroying the session object that also contains your authentication token. So, it's not actually the logout url that is logging you out but the session invalidate code.

I hope, it will help you understand what's happening underneath.

Comment: Can you show your xml configuration snippet for logout?

Comment: Thank you for your help, asking me the xml code made me check it out, so I found that stupid error :)

Comment: @MDP Glad, I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you register you custom LogoutHandler in SecurityConfig?
Something like:

```
http.logout()
                .logoutUrl("/pbl/login")
                .logoutSuccessHandler((request, response, authentication) -> customLogoutSuccessHandler().logout(request, response, authentication));
```

Comment: Yes, it's registered in my xml configuration file. Now, I made it work by invalidating the session inside my class CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler, but I can't understand why it works now...

Comment: Have you any rememberMeServices configured? If yes, make sure, that  you are also logout from here in your CustomLogoutHandler

Comment: No, I'm not using any rememberMeServices

Comment: I made a stupid error in the configuration file. I've written invalidate-session="false" instead of nvalidate-session="true":
Thank you for you help

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using `logoutRequestMatcher` since you are using

HTTP request to logout

i think you should use

- .logout()
- .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))

in your security configuration

Comment: I made a stupid error in the configuration file. I've written invalidate-session="false" instead of invalidate-session="true":
Thank you for you help